# How can I detect if I'm on a new page in iText PDF?

Tags: pdf, itext

I need to be able to tell to suppress column header if I'm on a new page that doesn't have rows to display in itext PDF. I found a custom PDfPageEvent class that we have that implements the original PdfPageEvent interface and implements the onStartPage method like so:

```
public class PdfPageEvent implements com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPageEvent {
    Report report;

    public PdfPageEvent(Report report) {
        this.report = report;
    }

    public void onStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        ReportTable table = report.getPageHeaderForPDF();
        if (table != null) {
            PdfPTable pTable = ((PdfReportTable) table).getTable();
            pTable.setTotalWidth(document.getPageSize().getRight() - document.getPageSize().getLeft() - 20);
            pTable.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 10, document.getPageSize().getTop() - 10, writer.getDirectContent());
        }
    }

    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        ReportTable table = report.getPageFooter();
        if (table != null) {
            PdfPTable pTable = ((PdfReportTable) table).getTable();
            pTable.setTotalWidth(document.getPageSize().getRight() - document.getPageSize().getLeft() - 20);
            pTable.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 10, document.getPageSize().getBottom() + 20, writer.getDirectContent());
        }
    }

    public void onOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
    }

    public void onCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
    }

    public void onParagraph(PdfWriter writer, Document document, float paragraphPosition) {
    }

    public void onParagraphEnd(PdfWriter writer, Document document, float paragraphPosition) {
    }

    public void onChapter(PdfWriter writer, Document document, float paragraphPosition, Paragraph title) {
    }

    public void onChapterEnd(PdfWriter writer, Document document, float paragraphPosition) {
    }

    public void onSection(PdfWriter writer, Document document, float paragraphPosition, int depth, Paragraph title) {
    }

    public void onSectionEnd(PdfWriter writer, Document document, float paragraphPosition) {
    }

    public void onGenericTag(PdfWriter writer, Document document, Rectangle rect, String text) {
    }
}
```

The logic for printing column headers lives in "report.getPageHeaderForPDF()".
How can I try to detect if I'm on a new pdf page and the writer.getDirectContent() has at least one row that is added to that new page?

I guess I can use these two detect if I'm on a new page:

```
int pageNumber = writer.getPageNumber();
int currentPageNumber = writer.getCurrentPageNumber();
```

But how do I figure out if there are any actual rows left to print on that page based on the content of writer.getDirectContent()?

Comment: I don't understand your code. For starters: it is **forbidden** to add content in the `onStartPage()` method! Furthermore: you are adding a table using `writeSelectedRows()` which means that the table won't be distributed over different pages automatically. If I were you, I would throw away my code and rephrase my requirement.

Comment: This is an existing code that I'm trying to improve.